# lxml has essentially nothing

Tags: python, package, lxml

The `lxml` package for Python seems to absolutely broken on my system. I am not sure of the problem, as all of the files are in place, it seems. My suspicion is that the problem is in `__init__.py`, but I don't have enough practice with the system to make an accurate diagnosis or fix the problem.

Here is some code that I think will help diagnose the problem:

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  7 2009, 18:45:15) 
[GCC 4.4.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
>>> dir(lxml)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
>>> print lxml.__path__
['/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml']
>>> c = open("/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml/__init__.py", "r")
>>> for line in c:
...     print line
... 
# this is a package



>>> c.close()
>>> import os
>>> os.system("ls /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml/")
builder.py      ElementInclude.py   __init__.py    sax.pyc
builder.pyc     ElementInclude.pyc  __init__.pyc       usedoctest.py
cssselect.py        _elementpath.py objectify.so       usedoctest.pyc
cssselect.pyc       _elementpath.pyc    pyclasslookup.py
doctestcompare.py   etree.so        pyclasslookup.pyc
doctestcompare.pyc  html        sax.py
0
>>>
```

Like I said, my suspicion is that `__init__.py` contains the problem, but I'm not 100% sure.

Also, I'm using Linux Mint 8 - the rough equivalent of Ubuntu 9.10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What tutorial or example where you following?  Can you provide the link to the documents you were using to see how it worked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you're just doing it wrong!  Try, e.g., `from lxml import etree`, and you should be able to use `etree` fully.  `import lxml` -- importing the **package**! -- does **not** give you implicit access to any of the package's **modules**!-)

Comment: Aha - therein lies the rub. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think all the lxml code is in subpackages.  Try

```
from lxml import etree
```

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly normal for a `__init__.py` file to have nothing in it: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages

The file is just there to let Python know that it's a package and not just a directory with a bunch of modules in it.

You just need to import the modules inside the package directly.

```
from lxml import etree, html
```

etc...